# Check existence of a directory in Makefile

Tags: macos, makefile

I want that my Makefile creates a directory if it doesn't already exist on OS X. Otherwise I would use `mkdir -p`, but it deletes whatever the directory already contains and I don't want that. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
all:
        DIR=../../aether3d_build
        ifneq ("$(wildcard $(DIR))","")
        mkdir $(DIR)
        endif
```

It causes the following error:

```
DIR=../../aether3d_build
ifneq ("","")
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `"",""'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifneq ("","")'
```

Comment: `mkdir -p` does not delete anything. `ifneq` is a make level construct not a shell one it goes *outside* recipe lines. You want a shell test there `[ -d "$$DIR" ] || mkdir "$DIR"` but as I started with `mkdir -p` is actually what you want since it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Thanks for the info, the problem was that I had two Makefiles copying stuff into the build directory and the other one got the directory's relative path wrong by one "../".